# How to set default_url_options in a DRY manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to set some of the options on `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` in an initializer. However, the problem is that this value may be `nil`, or it may be a hash with other options.

Example of the problem when using the reccomended method:

```
# config/application.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {protocol: 'https'}

# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "example.com"}

# config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "staging.example.com"}
```

Now `default_url_options` doesn't have `ssl: true` set.

The only way to accommodate both possibilities as far as I can tell is to set it to an empty hash if it's null, then add to the hash like so:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options ||= {}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = 'example.com'
```

This is not dry, and has to be done anywhere you wish to set this option unless you are absolutely sure none of the options have been set before *and* nobody will attempt to set one of the options in the future in a file which is loaded before this one.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like in env file.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options.merge(host: "staging.example.com")
```

Comment: This still requires two commands, since `default_url_options` is `nil` by default. You still have to start with `...default_url_options ||= {}` before this.

Comment: If you have `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {ssl: true}` in application.rb, that line won't be necessary.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's the best workaround. Really it seems this is a bug in rails, I'll file a report accordingly.